# How to keep track of selected item by GoBack() in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigation, uwp-xaml

I wrote a code where I can go to deferent pages and can go back using GoBack() method.

My problem is, when I go to a page, a blue bar shows up beside the name of the selected item in the navigation menu. But when I go back, the selected item doesn't change. How can I do that?

I hope I was able to explain. If I was not, please consider seeing the images that I have added.

Thanks.

Here is my code.

**XAML**

```
<NavigationView x:Name="navSample"
                IsPaneOpen="False"
                SelectionChanged="NavSample_SelectionChanged"
                SelectionFollowsFocus="Enabled" 
                IsBackButtonVisible="Auto"
                BackRequested="NavSample_BackRequested">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Item1" x:Name="SamplePage1Item" />
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Content="Item2" x:Name="SamplePage2Item" />
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Refresh" Content="Item3" x:Name="SamplePage3Item" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

**C#**

```
private void NavSample_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (navSample.SelectedItem == SamplePage1Item)
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SamplePage1));
    }
    else if (navSample.SelectedItem == SamplePage2Item)
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SamplePage2));
    }
    else if (navSample.SelectedItem == SamplePage3Item)
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SamplePage3));
    }
    else if (navSample.SelectedItem == navSample.SettingsItem)
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SamplePage2));
    }

    if (contentFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        navSample.IsBackEnabled = true;
    }
}
private void NavSample_BackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (contentFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        contentFrame.GoBack();

    }
}
```

Maybe these images can help you to understand better.

[Using Navigation Menu to browse page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4c0k.jpg)

[Using Navigation Menu to browse page (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTntx.jpg)

[Using back button and the expectation doesn't fulfill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWD2y.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the current page (SamplePage1, SamplePage2..etc) and set the selected menu item manually by:

```
SamplePage1Item.IsSelected = true;
```

You can write your logic like this:

```
private void NavSample_BackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (contentFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        contentFrame.GoBack();

        // setting selected menu 
        if(contentFrame.Content is SamplePage1) SamplePage1Item.IsSelected = true;
        else if(contentFrame.Content is SamplePage2) SamplePage2Item.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Because there is no link/relation between the content of the contentFrame and the selected menu. You either set the selected menu programmatically or it will change in response to tap/click.

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly. Thanks. But if there is a lot of menu item, it will be messy I guess!

Comment: You can use refelection to simplify

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, Type> _pages =
        new()
        {
            { "Requests", typeof(Pages.Requests.Requests) },
            { "Shift", typeof(Pages.Shift.Shift) }
        };

    public void NavigationViewItemInvoked(NavigationView navigationView, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationViewItem item = (NavigationViewItem)args.InvokedItemContainer;

        if(
            _pages.TryGetValue(item.Name, out Type t) &&
            t != _contentFrame.CurrentSourcePageType)
            switch (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
            {
                case true:
                    _contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.Settings.Settings));
                    break;

                case false:
                    _contentFrame.Navigate(t);
                    break;
            }
    }
```

for what its worth, you can add a dictionary entry for the settings also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I forgot the context tbh. Ha Ha Ha